# How to do a DensityPlot on a ParametricPlot

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration, parametric-functions

I have some code that works nicely, for what I want, but when I try to get a `DensityPlot` or `ContourPlot`, it will not work as it is a parametric equation using `NDSolve`. Is there a way to get a `DensityPlot` of this code?

```
 ClearAll["Global`*"]; Show[
  Table[sol = 
    NDSolve[{D[xtraj[t], 
        t] == (Sinh[2 xtraj[t] (t - 2)])/(Cosh[2 xtraj[t] (t - 2)]), 
      xtraj[0] == n}, xtraj[t], {t, 0, 4}];
    ParametricPlot[{xtraj[t], t} /. sol, {t, 0, 4}, 
  PlotRange -> All], {n, -3, 4 - 1, 1}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

For a contour plot use,

```
ListContourPlot[Flatten[Table[
    s = NDSolveValue[{D[xtraj[t], t] == 
        (Sinh[2 xtraj[t] (t - 2)])/(Cosh[2 xtraj[t] (t - 2)]), 
        xtraj[0] == n}, xtraj, {t, 0, 4}];
    Table[{s[t], t, n}, {t, 0, 4, .2}], {n, -3.2, 3.2, .2}], 1], 
 Contours -> Range[-4, 4], ImageSize -> Large, PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, Automatic},
 AspectRatio -> 2/3, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image]

The code for a density plot is similar.

```
ListDensityPlot[Flatten[Table[
    s = NDSolveValue[{D[xtraj[t], t] == 
        (Sinh[2 xtraj[t] (t - 2)])/(Cosh[2 xtraj[t] (t - 2)]), 
        xtraj[0] == n}, xtraj, {t, 0, 4}];
    Table[{s[t], t, n}, {t, 0, 4, .2}], {n, -3, 3, .2}], 1], 
ImageSize -> Large, AspectRatio -> 2/3, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `ParametricNDSolveValue` to get the solution `xtraj2` parametrized by `n`:

```
xtraj2 = ParametricNDSolveValue[{D[x[t], t] == Sinh[2 x[t] (t - 2)]/ Cosh[2 x[t] (t - 2)], 
   x[0] == n}, x, {t, 0, 4}, {n}];

ListContourPlot[Join @@ Table[{xtraj2[n][t], t, n}, {n, -4, 4, .1}, {t, 0, 4, .1}], 
  Contours -> Range[-3, 3]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can get an `InterpolatingFunction` from a table of data generated using `pf`

```
if = Interpolation[Join @@ Table[{{xtraj2[n][t], t}, n}, {t, 0, 4, .005}, 
  {n, -4, 4, 1}], InterpolationOrder -> 1];
```

and use it with `ContourPlot` or `DensityPlot`:

```
ContourPlot[if[x, y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, 0, 4},  Contours -> Range[-3, 3]]
```

[image]

```
DensityPlot[if[x, y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, 0, 4}, 
  MeshFunctions->{if[#, #2]&}, Mesh -> {Range[-3, 3]}, MeshStyle -> White,
  ColorFunction->"Rainbow", PerformanceGoal->"Quality"]
```

[image]

Comment: I am using the NDSolve Value to find the value of xtraj[t], I do not want the value of NDSolve, yet here all the plots are plotting the value of NDSolve instead of xtraj[t]. In this instance, it looks the same but if I vary the function it will not.

Comment: @Betty, not sure i understand your comment.